# Why is our website experiencing issues on Chrome iOS iPhone 5, iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome

[Here is our development website](https://goo.gl/pN3MGp).

On iPhone 6 or 5, using Google Chrome, we experience the following symptoms:

1. The page "jumps" randomly when touching links or buttons.
2. Sometimes, buttons and tabs do not work.

This also happens sometimes on other sites, such as Medium.com, but not with all websites.

These issues are not present on Safari or on Chrome but on Android.

We are not sure if this is a problem with our website coding or with Chrome on iOS. I did some searching but did not find any issues similar to ours.

Comment: Did you find a resolution or narrow down a cause? I suspect something relative to javascript/jquery but not sure. Thanks.

Comment: Not yet @mbmemb, we've deprioritized this issue and we're actually not sure if this is still happening. I've posted this on the Google Chrome forums and they suggested I download a beta version.